# More than one reference to a defined response object in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger

I am using swagger 2.0. I have a response object defined in "definitions" by the name "mobilePrice".
I have another response object named "Offer" which has properties "PriceOne" and "PriceTwo" referencing "mobilePrice".
Code looks like this:

```
"mobilePrice": {
  "properties": {
    "amount": {
      "type": "string"
     }
   }
}
"Offer": {
  "properties": {
     "PriceOne": {
       "$ref": "mobilePrice"
      },
      "PriceTwo": {
       "$ref": "mobilePrice"
      }
   }
}
```

When I try to see it on swagger UI. It does not show me the "PriceTwo" property at all. 
On trying various things , I figured that , the problem is occurring because of response object "mobilePrice" being referenced more than once. Can someone help me allow the reference to the same object more than once.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix your references. It may work not, but it officially that's not the right way, and support for it may be dropped. The correct form would be:

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/mobilePrice"
```

Second, the behavior you describe is a known issue. You can follow progress of it here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/186.